# CSS: Fixed child in overflow container is not visible

Tags: css, webkit, overflow, css-position, mozilla

I have a list that's `positioned: fixed;` with `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: auto;` defined. One of the child items are also `positioned: fixed;` and is positioned outside of the container.

In Mozilla the child item is visible, but in webkit browsers the child is not visible by the eye, but by the mouse. Here's an example, if you hover just above the list you'll see that the declaration `cursor: pointer;` is "triggered". Events attached to the child is also captured.

http://jsfiddle.net/h2YqV/

Any clues why it's not visible?

Comment: Visible for me on Chromium 36.

Comment: I also see it in Chrome 36, but in Safari it doesn't show as you described. I wonder if this is not a discrepancy in the implementation?

Comment: It's visible for me in Chrome 36

Comment: Where it doesn't work:Chrome 36.0.1985.125, Safari 7.0.5 (9537.77.4), Opera 22.0.1471.70

Comment: In Opera 23.0.1522.60 it works. If I place a wrapper around the list and position the list to `absolute` it works - http://jsfiddle.net/h2YqV/9/. Kind of sucks to have to do that, but well well.